# Django duplicate sites, 1 instance

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have built my Django application which uses the Django admin as a CMS. I am hosting on Heroku:

**myApp**
**myProject**
**templates**
manage.py
requirements.txt

I have now been asked to duplicate it for multiple countries, but each country will have totally different content (all assets, logic, models will be identical). The only content that changes is the content written to the CMS.

The easy/ugly option would be to literally duplicate the code and its database and run it on a separate Heroku dyno for each country.

What is the best way to keep this under the same host/Django installation?

Comment: Is there different content in the wording, or the actual logic of the code? If you're re-designing the entire website for another country, what is there to 'save' in order to make the process easier?

Comment: Sorry I should have made this clearer. The only thing that will change between regions is the content which is updated via a CMS. the design is excatly the same.

Comment: You can install the same app as multiple sites. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#module-django.contrib.sites

Comment: But how would that look in the CMS? Could I drill down into each app separately?